# How to read an Image file in Goole Colab using PIL Library?

Tags: python, file, file-upload, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to run this piece of code but I'm getting the same error repeatedly. At first I tried it in Pycharm IDE but got an error "file not found", I thought maybe there's some package installation issue. So, I started working in Google Colab but here, too, I'm getting the same error, can someone point out what's the issue? I'm sharing the code snippet:

```
          from PIL import Image

          strokeimgs = ['dance stroke 1.png']
          strokeimg = Image.open(strokeimgs)
```

[image: Error Message]

I get this error message as a result, is this issue related to PIL library or is it related to the file location?

Comment: can you show us where the file is located in the drive

Comment: Are you mounting the Google Drive in Colab?

Comment: Yes, I did mount my Google Drive. Actually, I was making one mistake which I have explained in detail below. Please see the answer below. Thank you @Orbital

Comment: @Dan Nagle Yes, I did upload it, please see the detail below. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I was making one mistake which I was not even aware of. The thing is that I uploaded images files to a folder named "project_folder" which is residing inside a folder i.e. "Assignment_2_folder", which is my working directory. So, you've to upload your files directly to the working directory, otherwise, it will not be able to read it. I have attached the image which will make it further clear. Thus, I uploaded my images files to my working directory i.e. Assignment_2_folder, it was then able to read it.

[image]